# Clicking a menuItem through sendMessage C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working with a windows CE application that fetch text from another application.
I was able to get my target window through..

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

FindWindow("#NETCF_AGL_BASE_","Barcode");
```

I used WinCE remote spy++ but the I wasnt able to locate the handler for the contextMenu in picture.

I am able to click a certain coordinate in my OWN APPLICATION screen using my function below:

```
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

    //This simulates a left mouse click
    public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
    {
        SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
    }
```

BUT I cant use it to click a point in another window.
How can I use sendMessage that clicks the "Trigger" contextMenu as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Try [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) after you get other application window handle.

Comment: Thanks for a very quick response! It worked!
SetForegroundWindow shows it up. Is there a way to do it while the program is in background? I mean I just want to trigger it but not to show it up.
Thanks :)

Comment: I think much better would be for you to look for a library that does same thing as this application do. I bet you can find barcode reading from image library so you won't need to do hacks :)

Comment: Yes, I recommend to built your own decode barcode app based on any of the available free barcode decoder libs. For example: zxingnet.codeplex.com which is a lib based on the android used ZXing. On the other side you may look inside the code of the app and may extend it to send events or messages for foreign apps. But again, I would go with CameraCaptureDialog and a free decoder lib.